# Highlight Multiple Substrings in a String in Python

Tags: python, string, replace, format

I would like to highlight the substrings in a list, that exist in another string, in python.

I have a list called `highlight_list`:

```
highlight_list=['cat','dog','catdog']
```

I have a string called `text_main`:

```
text_main='The cat and the dog were dancing together.  They looked like a catdog, not a dogcat'
```

i want the output to be a string named `text_highlight` that looks like this:

```
text_highlight
```

The **cat** and the **dog** were dancing together.  They looked like a **catdog**, not a dogcat

Instead of Bold, maybe a yellow highlighter block fill or something.

I have tried to join them, then use string.replace but this didn't work - something like this:

```
highlight_str='|'.join(highlight_list)
text_highlight=text_main.replace(highlight_str, '\033[44;33m{}\033[m'.format(text_main)))
```

Comment: What's you are looking for is probably [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

Comment: do you have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you use `\033[44;33m{}\033[m'.format(text_main)` which will make the whole text colored.

You can use [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) instead of replace, and make the match colored instead of the whole string.

You can make the highlight_str using a non capture group `(?:` between word boundaries `\b` to prevent partial matches.

```
highlight_str = r"\b(?:" + '|'.join(highlight_list) + r")\b"
```

The pattern will look like

```
\b(?:cat|dog|catdog)\b
```

For example

```
import re

text_main = 'The cat and the dog were dancing together.  They looked like a catdog, not a dogcat'
highlight_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'catdog']
highlight_str = r"\b(?:" + '|'.join(highlight_list) + r")\b"
text_highlight = re.sub(highlight_str, '\033[44;33m\g<0>\033[m', text_main)
print(text_highlight)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Once I needed to highlight words in the text case-insensitively, but I didn’t want to use regexp because of the need to escape special characters in the text. Maybe someone will need a native python version:

```
def highlight_keyword(text: str, keyword: str, opening_symbol: str, closing_symbol: str) -> str:
    text_lowered = text.lower()
    keyword_lowered = keyword.lower()
    keyword_len = len(keyword_lowered)
    highlight_symbols_len = len(opening_symbol) + len(closing_symbol)
    index = text_lowered.find(keyword_lowered)
    text_highlited = text
    while True:
        keyword_start_index = text_lowered.find(keyword_lowered, index)
        if keyword_start_index == -1:
            break
        keyword_end_index = keyword_start_index + keyword_len
        text_highlited = text_highlited[:keyword_start_index] + opening_symbol + \
                         text_highlited[keyword_start_index:keyword_end_index] + closing_symbol + \
                         text_highlited[keyword_end_index:]
        text_lowered = text_lowered[:keyword_start_index] + opening_symbol + \
                       text_lowered[keyword_start_index:keyword_end_index] + closing_symbol + \
                       text_lowered[keyword_end_index:]
        index = keyword_end_index + highlight_symbols_len
    return text_highlited
```

Works like this:
[image: Example]